# Setting shopware version compatibility in plugins

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

When developing a shopware plugin i want to define which SW versions my plugin is tested and compatible with.

What is best practice in terms of marking my plugin for version compatibility?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the `composer.json` of your plugin you can use the [`require`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links) property to set the version of the Shopware `core` package you require.

```json
"require": {
    "shopware/core": "~v6.5.0"
}
```

See the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md) on how to specify the required version.

In addition you can also add the `shopware/administration` and/or `shopware/storefront` packages to be required, if they are needed for full functionality of your plugin.